# Unable to select 'settings activity' in android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, settings

I am following the tutorial (9.2), it asks to add a 'settings activity', when i try to select it, it is greyed out and says that it 'requires androidx support'. I can find no reference to androidx support in the tutorial and have tried googling the problem to no avail. I have even loaded the completed project from the master files to compare their code with mine, i can find no reference to androidx. I am using android studio 3.4.1

Answer (score 9):

As it says, it requires androidx support. You need to enable AndroidX in your project. Add these two lines to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Setting these two gradle plugin flags to true means that Android Plugin will use appropriate AndroidX library instead of support Library & will rewrite their binaries. Also note that, since you need to use AndroidX in this project, you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher.

For knowing more how to migrate an entire project to AndroidX, please follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: Many thanks for your input Ahmedaljubair, unfortunately your suggestion di not work for me. As i said, I have loaded the completed project from the master files and compared their code, they're not using androidx for this project (and there is no mention of androidx in the tutorials) .... I persevere! :(

Comment: @SteveC, Could you please then share the link to that particular video of the tutorial series, which you've mentioned as `9.2`? Other than that, it's really hard to decipher where the problem is or what's going wrong here.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-adding-settings-to-app/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#0

Comment: 2.1 Explore the Settings Activity template.
To include the Settings Activity template in an app project in Android Studio, follow these steps:

Copy the DroidCafeOptionsUp project folder, and rename it to DroidCafeWithSettings. Run the app to make sure it runs properly.
Select app at the top of the Project > Android pane, and choose New > Activity > Settings Activity.

Comment: ...and that's where i see the 'Settings activity' greyed out with the comment 'requires androidx support'

Comment: @SteveC, the codelab tutorial series that you're following was not updated recently but you're using the most updated Android Studio version `3.4.1` as you've previously mentioned. Now, using this Setting Activity template requires AndroidX support, which is not updated anywhere in that series codelab. Hence, please follow my answer and add AndroidX support & then follow the migration guide.

Comment: For example: they haven't updated this RecyclerView tutorial in the same series to AndroidX too, so it must have not been updated for a long time: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-create-recycler-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#3

Comment: I'd rather encourage you to follow this updated tutorial of Android fundamentals which uses AndroidX, Kotlin & updated on 2019: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/android-kotlin-fundamentals/

Comment: I'll certainly do that, thank you. Last question, do you have any idea why the completed code from the master files also does not use androidx ? (but uses a 'settings activity')?

Comment: @SteveC, yes this course was last updated on September-November 2018 and `AndroidX` was released for its use in production on September 2018 at the same time. This course was not updated with it but the later ones were. Ref: AndroidX release notes: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/archive/androidx

Comment: @SteveC, so the `Settings Activity` could be accessed on Pre-AndroidX too, but with the same layout without `AndroidX` components. After the updates, Android Studio removed that option. Please accept my answer because migrating to AndroidX is the only solution to this accessing Pre-AndroidX options/activities from IDE problem.