# Android: Exoplayer - ExtractorMediaSource is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5573-media-playback-on-android-with-exoplayer-getting-started) to implement the Exoplayer. But the ExtractorMediaSource class is deprecated. I need to play video from a remote url. What is the alternative to use in this situation?

```
val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource
  .Factory(DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, userAgent))
  .setExtractorsFactory(DefaultExtractorsFactory())
  .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Are you using `ExoPlayer` of version `2.10.0` or higher? Then, use `ProgressiveMediaSource` instead of `ExtractorMediaSource` ([Reference Release Note](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md#2100))

Comment: Doing this is giving Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:21:5-562:19 to override.

Comment: Hello @DragonFire, this manifest merger error is due to the prohibited usage of both AppCompat and AndroidX dependencies at the same time. Please look at this answer for ensuring you have properly migrated all dependencies to AndroidX: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556363/11040422

Comment: Also, please check if your gradle is updated to com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later and compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.

Answer (score 6):

**ExtractorMediaSource** is deprecated.**ProgressiveMediaSource** is updated source factory

```
ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory())
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("url or path")))
```

Answer (score 2):

`ExtractorMediaSource` deprecated using with [2.14.0](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/RELEASENOTES.md)

Remove `ExtractorMediaSource`. Use `ProgressiveMediaSource` instead.

You should use new version : `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2'`

```kotlin
      val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
      val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
      val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(mediaItem)
      exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
```

Comment: Thanks so much bro!!! U just saved my time, i had given 1 day to upgrade EXOPLAYER from 2.10.8 to 2.18.7 <3

Comment: You're welcome :) Good works.